# How to simulate cron in Prestashop?

Tags: php, cron, prestashop

I'm creating a PrestaShop module for product import and need to simulate `cron scheduled tasks`. Can't use actual `cron`, so have to simulate it. Should I hook it to some action? Is this a good practice?

Process will import about 10k items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use cron (for whatever reason), then you could make an external script that will call a special URL on your PrestaShop site and act like a cron.

**Please note** that you might hit server limits if executing a long running request over HTTP instead of terminal.

You can also read [how WordPress does](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/) it so you can get an idea.

I don't recommend running long running processes when a visitor visits your site because it will considerably slow down your site.

Such processes as product imports should run in the background.

You could also do a Google search in order to find alternatives for cron.

Comment: I want to make it flexible, so even if client's host doesn't allow cron jobs it would work normally.

Comment: Understood. An external service can `ping` your secret URL and work like a `cron job`.

Comment: I though about external service for clients, but don't want to cointain with external scripts.

Yeah, server limits is another problem, so I'm thinking to cut import file to pieces of 100 products each, and then script should import that file with 100 products and make HTTP request at ending with special URL to import next file with 100 products and so on till all files imported. (Sorry for weak english skills)

Comment: Kinda, one more question. Is it ok with my idea in previous comment? And how it's possible to check in external script if calling site has bought module from prestashop.com marketplace?

Comment: If your module is going to be available in PrestaShop marketplace then write detailed instructions in the documentation how to execute the cron job. You could also add cron job as a requirement. Almost all hosting plans out there have cron job support.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the true answer to the question:

If you use the Prestashop module "Cronjob" you will actually not need a crontab system on the server.
"Basic Cron" tasks are being registered on a public webservice from Prestashop themselves (at http://webcron.prestashop.com/crons). 
That service will periodically call your website's /modules/cronjob/... url to trigger your cronjobs.

It's not the most reliable nor controllable solution, but it's a nice gesture from Prestashop.